# Using LaunchImage as background (iOS)?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to use my Launch Image like a background during the application execution, but I've tried many ways and none of them worked. I want to do this because I have a single launch image for iPhone 3.5i, iPhone 4i, iPad and iPad with Retina, and I don't know how to load a specific image for each case.

There is some way to load a Launch Image as background, or I need to create statements for each case when loading a background?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query launch image at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789927/query-launch-image-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just found out that you can create ImageSets which are device specific.

You just need to open the attribute inspector and change it from "Universal" to "Device Specific" and you can create a fully openable image.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the image you used as your launch image and put it in a image view that is in your view controller.